# Vue - Iterating through an object after deleting the child objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue which is well documented on SO and other forums, where one iterates through an array and gets an error as the object might not be defined in the DOM or might not have loaded yet.

For example the below - if `name` or `child` is iterated too you will get an `undefined` error - as the `child` has not been defined. However if you were to add `{ child: { name: '' } }` to the `parent` object it would work fine as it has been defined.

```
<p> {{ parent.child.name }} </p>

data: () => ({
parent: {}
})
```

One can get around that by testing to see if the `parent` object had no data like so:

```
<div> v-if="Object.keys(parent).length != 0" >

     <p> {{ parent.child.name }} </p>

</div>
```

The issue I am having is that if I:
1. *Create* the page with the nested objects.
2. Add new data to the object.
3. Delete the added data.

I get an undefined error as the nested array no longer exits.

I can re-add the empty nested array again, but their must be a more slick way to check if the object is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vue you can use `watch` property to keep the track.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    parent: {
      child: {}
    }
  }),
  watch: {
    parent: function(val) {
      console.log(val.child.length);
      if (val.child.length === 0) {
        this.parent.child = {};
      }
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p> {{ parent.child.name }} </p>
</div>
```